# Union type values passed to a method cannot be invoked

Tags: typescript, typescript1.4

The following code will produce an error: *Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature*.

If the interfaces were the same (both contained 'a' for example) everything works fine.
Why?

```
interface Foo { a:string }
interface Bar { b:string }

var stuff: Foo[] | Bar[];

function doStuff(thing: Foo | Bar) {
    var index = stuff.indexOf(thing);
}
```

Comment: Should stuff be an [array of (Foos or Bars)] instead of [(an array of Foos) or (an array of Bars)]? (I'm not familiar with typescript so maybe I'm misreading the type signature)

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. Feel free to post it as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now `stuff` is the union of Foo arrays and Bar arrays. You're trying to check an item of type (Foo or Bar) against it. If `stuff` has actual type Foo[] and `thing` has actual type Bar, you have a type mismatch.

The type of stuff should be an array of (Foo or Bar).

```
var stuff: (Foo | Bar)[];
```